How to create from an int an instance of a Python's enum.Flag that uses a default member for powers of two in the int not contained in the enum?
Say I have the following Flag enum:
class MyFlags(Flag):
  FLAG0    = 0x01
  FLAG1    = 0x02
  #INVALID = 0x04
  FLAG3    = 0x08
  #INVALID = 0x10
  #INVALID = 0x20
  #INVALID = 0x40
  INVALID  = 0x80

I would like to create an instance of MyFlags from an int, such that, if the int is composed of powers of two that are not defined in MyFlags, then MyFlags.INVALID is returned instead. In other words:
>>> Flags(0x01), Flags(0x03), Flags(0x04), Flags(0x85)
(<MyFlags.FLAG0: 1>, <MyFlags.FLAG0|FLAG1: 3>, <MyFlags.INVALID: 128>,<MyFlags.FLAG0|INVALID>: 129)

Thus, it is easy to identify, if an invalid flag has been decoded, i.e.:
>>> rx_byte = 0x081
>>> MyFlags.INVALID in MyFlags(rx_byte)
True


You need to add your own _missing_ method:
class Flags(Flag):
    #
    FLAG0    = 0x01
    FLAG1    = 0x02
    #INVALID = 0x04
    FLAG3    = 0x08
    #INVALID = 0x10
    #INVALID = 0x20
    #INVALID = 0x40
    INVALID  = 0x80
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        extra = value & ~cls._flag_mask_
        if extra:
            value = value & cls._flag_mask_ | cls.INVALID.value
        return super()._missing_(value)

and in use:
>>> Flags(0x01), Flags(0x03), Flags(0x04), Flags(0x85)
(<Flags.FLAG0: 1>, <Flags.FLAG0|FLAG1: 3>, <Flags.INVALID: 128>, <Flags.FLAG0|INVALID: 129>)

You do need to be more careful if containment testing, as only ints give accurate results:
# integer containment checking requires 3.12+
>>> 1 in Flags
True
>>> 3 in Flags
True
>>> 4 in Flags
False
>>> Flags(4) in Flags
True


Note that _missing_ is currently public, and _flag_mask_ is not, but I suspect it will be in Python 3.14.

Disclosure:  I am the author of the Python stdlib Enum, the enum34 backport, and the Advanced Enumeration (aenum)  library.

Thanks for the idea! To avoid accessing a private attribute, I ended up iterating over all enum members to determine flag_mask. It would be nice to have access to this attribute in future version of the enum module. Thanks also for the enum module!

If MyFlags(x) fails, it raises a ValueError; just catch that.
try:
    x = MyFlags(15)
except ValueError:
    x = ...

(Valid combinations, of course, do not raise:
>>> MyFlags(11)
<MyFlags.FLAG0|FLAG1|FLAG3: 11>

)

Thanks for the suggestion :) I could do that, but I was hoping I could avoid using try ... except blocks all over the code by customizing my enum.Flags derived class.
